# Using SimUserIncludeDirs when running Simulink model from the command line

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model that includes a lot of additional source code. The include folders are specified in the "Include Directories*" of the model Configuration Parameters.

However, I need to include an additional folder that is only known at the project build time. The model is run by the CI/CD using the `sim` command. One option to add additional folder is with the [SimUserIncludeDirs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/include-directories.html) option. But it appears that when this option is used all the folders included in the Configuration Parameters are cleared. Then I have to include the same folders again the parameters for SimUserIncludeDirs.

Is there any way to avoid this duplication? To set an option to `sim`, which may not be SimUserIncludeDirs, that *adds* an additional folder?

MATLAB 2022b